# Git - "error: RPC failed" when pushing a large commit

Tags: git

When trying to push a commit that changes several thousand lines in a large text file, or adds such a file, I get the following error:

```
git push
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 264.00 KiB | 3.34 MiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Pushing smaller commits works fine, as does pushing deletions of even large files. Other people pushing into the same repository don't have this problem. I have tried increasing `http.postBuffer`. I'm using Git on Windows.

Comment: Did you try increasing your post buffer?  IE `git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400`  You can check it by  -- `git config --get http.postBuffer` --  If you don't get a response .. It's defaulting to 1MB.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, as I mentioned above.